# What is the difference between uic and rcc (or pyuic4 and pyrcc4)

Tags: qt, user-interface, pyqt

According to the Qt wiki, both definitions seem very similar to me..

```
The rcc resource compiler parses the XML and generates C/C++ code

The uic reads an XML format user interface definition (.ui) file as generated by Qt Designer and creates a corresponding C++ header file
```

So they each take an xml file and make it into c++.  So what's the difference that you would use one over the other?

(Incidentally I'm looking to use `pyQt` with QT Designer (&pyrcc4?) to make a simple `GUI` for an existing `DLL`)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

rcc is a Qt resource compiler: [the Qt resource system is a platform-independent mechanism for storing binary files in the application's executable.](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/resources.html)

uic is Qt user interface compiler: [it creates a corresponding C++ header file from ui file generated in Qt Designer](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/uic.html)